# How to achieve a similar aesthetic?

Tags: raw

This Lyle Ashton Harris photo is one of my favourites. Anyone have any tips as to how he could have achieved this image?

[image]

Comment: Please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?" questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/) and edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, too. Thank you!

Comment: Even though this is a simple negative, read about [solarisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solarization_(photography)) which creates images with an effect similar to this.

Comment: [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871) and [What's the best way to ask a “How do I achieve this effect?” question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/15871)

Answer (score 3):

It's a [negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_(photography)). Lights are dark, darks are light. Here's the inverted image:

[image]

Comment: Is it just me or does it look ever so slightly solarized?

Comment: @Hueco to me, the original looks like a photo of a print of a negative, hanging on a wall under an art lamp. More intense lighting at top, falls off as it goes lower, with a bit of light bloom in the middle, reflecting into the camera. Of course, that light pattern got inverted when I inverted the image...

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The jeans and hair just looked not quite right. But, the photo of a print makes sense.

Comment: @Hueco the hair's just backlit and he is wearing light jeans